# inputs in html and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a form where the name, stock and price data come from the bank and total price is calculated at the time the quantity is entered.

I am using a while and I bring all the products and along with input I create the screen, but I can not calculate the total price of the second record onwards.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id_cliente'])) {$idcliente = $_GET['id_cliente']; } 

   include ('header.php');
   require_once '../gets/DB_Functions.php';
   $db = new DB_Functions();

   $rs=$db->listaclientes($idcliente);
   while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
   {
      $nome=$rows['nome'];

      $datacadastro=$rows['data_cadastro'];
      $endereco=$rows['endereco'];
      $bairro=$rows['bairro'];
      $cidade=$rows['cidade'];
      $uf=$rows['uf'];
      $cep=$rows['cep'];
      $celular=$rows['celular'];
      $email=$rows['login'];
   }
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clinica.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function()  {
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'observacao' );
      };
    </script> 
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h3>
      Cliente : <?php echo $nome ?><BR>
      </h3>
      <div>
             <label for="tipoAtendimento"> Endereco : </label><?php echo $endereco?><BR>
             <label for="tipoAtendimento"> Bairro :</label> <?php echo $bairro?><BR>
             <label for="tipoAtendimento">Cidade : </label><?php echo $cidade?><BR>
             <label for="tipoAtendimento">Estado : </label><?php echo $uf?><BR>
             <label for="tipoAtendimento"> cep :</label> <?php echo $cep ?><span></span>
             <label for="tipoAtendimento"> Celular :</label> <?php echo $celular ?></span><br>
             <label for="tipoAtendimento"> Email :</label> <?php echo $email ?>

      </div>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="principal.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>

      </ol>
    </section>
          <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div>
           <div class="box">
             <div class="box">


                  <div class="row" >

                             <div class="form-group has-success col-md-7">
                                 <label for="tipoAtendimento" >
                                    Forma de Pagamento
                                </label>

                                <select id="tipoAtende" name="tipoAtende" onclick ="updatetexto();">
                                    <?php 

                                      $rs=$db->buscarformapagamento();
                                      while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
                                        $idforma=$rows['idforma'];
                                        $desc=$rows['descricao'];

                                        echo '<option value="'.$idforma.'">'.$desc.'</option>';
                                      }
                                    ?>


                                </select>
                              </div>
                               <div class="form-group has-success col-md-5">
                                 <label for="tipoAtendimento" >
                                    Bonificação
                                </label>

                                <select id="tipoAtende" name="tipoAtende" onclick ="updatetexto();">
                                    <?php 

                                        echo '<option value="1">Sim</option>';
                                        echo '<option value="2">Não</option>';

                                    ?>


                                </select>
                              </div>


                </div>
                  <div class="row" >



                  <div class="row" >
                      <div class="form-group has-success col-md-12">
                         <label>Pedido</label>
                         <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">Descrição do Produto</th>
                              <th scope="col">Estoque</th>
                              <th scope="col">Qtd vendida</th>
                              <th scope="col">Preço</th>
                              <th scope="col">Total a pagar</th>
                            </tr>
                               <?php 
                               $total=0;
                                  $rs=$db->distribuicaoprodutos();
                                    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
                                      $id=$rows['id'];
                                      $desc=$rows['nome'];
                                      $preco=$rows['preco'];
                                      $estoque=$rows['estoque'];

                                              ?>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>

                                        <input type="text" name="desc" size="70" id="desc" value="<?php echo $desc ?>" >

                                      </td>
                                      <td>

                                         <input type="text" name="estoque" size="5" id="estoque"  value="<?php echo $estoque ?>">

                                      </td>
                                      <td>

                                         <input type="text" name="qtd" size="10" id="qtd" onblur="total()">

                                      </td>
                                      <td>

                                        <input type="text" name="preco" id="preco" size="15"  value="<?php echo $preco?>" >
                                      </td>
                                      <td>

                                             <input type="text" name="total" size="20" id="total" >

                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                               <?php } ?>

                          </table>
                      </div>

                      <table>
                           <tr>
                                  <td>

                                       Total de itens <input type="text" name="itens" id="itens" size="15"  value="0" >
                                  </td>
                                  <td>

                                        Total de Desconto  <input type="text" name="apagar" size="20" id="apagar" value="0">

                                  </td>
                                  <td>

                                        Valor a Pagar  <input type="text" name="apagar" size="20" id="apagar" value="0">

                                  </td>
                                  </tr>
                      </table>

                  </div>
                  <div class="row" >
                      <div class="form-group has-success col-md-12">
                         <label>Observações</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-success col-md-12"> 
                        <textarea  class="ckeditor" name="observcao" id="observcao" rows="7" cols="160" placeholder="Coloque Observações necessarias "></textarea>
                      </div>

                  </div>


                  <div class="row" >
                      <div class="form-group has-success col-md-12"> 
                          <div class="form-group has-success col-md-2">
                           <button  class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" id="Gravar" size="10"  onclick="gravar()">Gravar</button>
                        </div>

                       <div class="form-group has-success col-md-2">

                         <button  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" id="voltar" size="10" ><a href="distribuicao_hconsultar.php" style="color: #FFF">Voltar</a></button>


                       </div>
                      </div>

                  </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function total(){
        var qtd =document.getElementById("qtd").value;
        qtd=parseFloat(qtd.replace(",", "."));

        var preco =parseFloat(document.getElementById("preco").value);
        var total = preco*qtd;
        var itens=parseFloat(document.getElementById("itens").value);
        var vltot=parseFloat(document.getElementById("apagar").value);
        var apagar=vltot+apagar;
        var totitens=itens+qtd;

        document.getElementById("total").value=total;
        document.getElementById("itens").value=totitens;
        document.getElementById("apagar").value=apagar;

    }
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

function gravar()
{



    // pegando os valore nos campo e enviando para gravação

  var idcliente           = <?php echo $idcliente?>;
  var idpet               = <?php echo  $id?>;
  var select              = document.getElementById('tipoAtende');
  var tipoAtendimento   = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
 // console.log(select); // pt
  //var idtipoatendimento =;
  var peso                = <?php echo $peso ?>;
  var vacinacao           = '<?php echo $vacinacao ?>';
  var vermifugacao        = '<?php echo $ultima_vermifugacao ?>';
  var banho               = '<?php echo $ultimo_banho ?>';
  var sintomas            = document.getElementById("sintomas").value;
  var anaminese           = document.getElementById("anaminese").value;
  var diagnostico         = document.getElementById("diagnostico").value;
  var tratamento          = document.getElementById("tratamento").value;
  var retorno             = document.getElementById("retorno").value;
  //if(retorno<)
```

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: ok, i put with array and nothing